# Newline in node label in dot (graphviz) language

Tags: newline, graphviz, dot

Does anyone know how to put newline in the label of the node? \n is not working - instead some new nodes appear.

Comment: **TL;DR: Use `\n`.**

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This works for me [as documented](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#k:escString):

```
digraph {
    n[label="two\nlines"]
    "on\nthree\nlines"
}
```

Either put in in a label attribute (my preference), or use it as the node's name, but always enclose it with double quotes.

Comment: It appears that `'n` is to explicitly center the lines.  While this is default behavior (on mine at least), if you were to specify this globally (I assume there is such an option) then `'n` would override that setting while `\n` would not (presumably).

Comment: @altendky Which version is needed in order to get `'n` to work? With 2.29.20120504.0446, this still doesn't work. Only `\n` works (or `\r` to right align, and `\l` to left align). Furthermore, this only works for the first two lines. All the subsequent lines are centered, whatever escape sequence is used.

Comment: My previous comment was based only on the link.  I just tried it and `'r` does not seem to work, only `\r`.  Also, `\r` applies right justify the line _before_ it (ditto for left).  I have 2.29.20121205.0545 but I have no idea when this was implemented or to what degree.  My test node is: `multilineNode           [label="line 1 asdf\nline 2 asfdasdfd\nline 3 fd\rline 4 fdasfasddddddd\nline 5 fdsf\l d \N\r"]`  Note `\N` to get the node name in there too.

Comment: In case anyone wants to combine fonts, with a newline, html labels, specifically `<BR/>` can be used eg `label=<<B>Word1</B> <BR/> Word2>`

Comment: This answer is horrifically unclear. All it is saying is to use `\n`...

Answer (score 11):

Try "`\\n`" that works: `dot.node('test', label="line1\\nline2")`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\n` character

With [`graphviz`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) package, this would give

```py
from graphviz import Digraph
d=Digraph()
d.node('test',label='line 1\\nline 2')
print(d.source)
```

This would give

```
digraph {
    test [label="line 1\nline 2"]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`<BR/>` tag in a [HTML-like label](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) creates a line break.

```
digraph {
    n[label=<two<BR/>lines>]
}
```

This can come handy when the `\n` syntax cannot be used. Most notably, the [`graphviz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphviz) package for LaTeX can have problems parsing `\` inside `.tex` files, and using the HTML-like syntax is a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was also important to me, as I was using graphviz to generate detailed UML diagrams and needed to use escape characters in the labels.  However, using the Python package, I encountered a bug in how escape characters are handled, so some of the recommended solutions did not work.

For example:

```
from graphviz import Digraph
d=Digraph()
d.node('test',label='line 1\\nline 2')
print(d.source)
```

Generated the following (note that escaping does not work):

```
digraph {
    test [label="line 1\\nline 2"]
}
```

Workarounds such as using a single backslash, rawstrings, are infuriatingly ineffective.  However, the workaround that did ultimately work was the following:

```
    s = graphviz.Source(d.source.replace('\\\\', '\\'))
    s.render('my_uml')
```

I don't know if this bug in handling escape characters is in the Python bindings (v0.12) or graphviz itself (v2.44), but since others may encounter it, I wanted to offer this solution.