# Multiline tooltip for pydot graph

Tags: graphviz, pydot

I would like to add multiline tool-tip for the nodes in the graph I am generating using pydot. Here is what I am doing:

```
node = pydot.Node('abc', style='filled', fillcolor='#CCFF00', fontsize=12)
txt = 'foo' + '\n' + 'test'
node.set_tooltip(txt)
```

The tool tip that I get to see appears as "foo\ntest'

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks
Abhijit

Answer (score 15):

It seems the new line character is supported for labels and names ([Newline in node label in dot (graphviz) language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10841973/4354522)), but tool tips are put directly into the resultant HTML, which does not see "\n" as a special character.

Using direct character codes is an alternative. (see [Formatting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_reference_overview) & [ASCII Control Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart))

```
node = pydot.Node('abc', style='filled', fillcolor='#CCFF00', fontsize=12)

# specify HTML Carriage Return (\r) and/or Line Feed (\n) characters directly
txt = 'foo' + '&#13;&#10;' + test'

node.set_tooltip(txt)
```

Or some simple pre-processing would allow you to keep the '\n' form:

```
node.set_tooltip(txt.replace('\n', '&#10;'))
```

- Note that for [HTML-Like Labels](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/shapes.html#html), using the above replace-with-entity in the only way to have multiline-tooltips.

Comment: Any reason this isn't the accepted answer @Abhijit? Works for me.