# graphviz no line break (.dot)

Tags: graph, newline, graphviz, dot

I'm working with graphviz on LinuxArch. If I print my .svg I use the command `dot -Tsvg example.dot -o exampale.svg`. My graph is printed and that works fine. I read some other questions on that topic [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841135/newline-in-node-label-in-dot-graphviz-language),  [Link 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569166/how-can-i-type-a-newline-using-the-latex-graphviz-package), also the documentation on [graphviz.org](https://graphviz.org/documentation/) didn't give me a clue.

Question: I want to line break in a node. How I can do it?

The following code is working, but not always. Full Code:

```
digraph G {
    //general settings
    graph [fontname="Arial"];
    node [fontname="Arial"];
    edge [fontname="Arial"];

    //data of graph
    subgraph cluster_1
    {
        label = "Cluster 1";
        style=filled;
        color="#E0E0E0";
        margin=20;
        node [style=filled,color=white];
        "I'm text" -> "I want a donat.";
        "I want a donat." -> a1[label="Love food,\nlove it so much!"];
    }

    subgraph cluster_2
    {
        label = "Cluster 2";
        style=filled;
        color="#E0E0E0";
        margin=20;
        node [style=filled,color=white];
        Start -> a2[label="sit amet,\nconsetetur"];
        a2 ->
        {
            b2[label="Lorem Impsum\ndollar sit amet."];
        }
    }
}
```

Result: (Green marked is working and the problem is Red marked.)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you are confusing node and edge declarations.

Try changing the lines

```
    "I'm text" -> "I want a donat.";
    "I want a donat." -> a1[label="Love food,\nlove it so much!"];
```

into

```
    a1[label="Love food,\nlove it so much!"];
    "I'm text" -> "I want a donat.";
    "I want a donat." -> a1;
```

What this actually does is that `a1` is defined as a node with a label. The node id `a1` can then be used to declare edges between nodes.

Here is an other example, with explicit node declarations for all nodes, and then the edge declarations using the node identifiers:

```
    imtext[label="I'm text"];
    donat[label="I want a donat."];
    a1[label="Love food,\nlove it so much!"];

    imtext -> donat -> a1;
```

Comment: Thank you, @marapet that solved my problem. I didn't expect that I made an "error" at declaration.